# Filtrar tabelas dinâmicas em vba

Tags: array, microsoft-excel, vba, tabela-html

Tenho duas tabelas dinâmicas e quero ir selecionando sempre o mesmo item nelas, que no caso são nomes. Então tenho uma regra que pega em uma outra planilha os nomes e do lado o número de pendências, caso a pessoa tenha mais de 20 pendências ela deve ser marcada automaticamente nas duas tabelas dinâmicas, mas só ela. E nenhuma outra pessoa, porém eu não consigo fazer ele ir fazendo isso um por um. Às vezes vai, às vezes não.

```
Sub dinamycs()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim MyArray(1 To 152) As String
    i = 0
    j = 3
    Sheets("Pendência_Agenda").Activate
    Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each MyCell In Selection
    j = j + 1
    If Cells(j, 2).Value > 20 And Not MyCell.Value = "" And Not MyCell.Value = "################" Then
        i = i + 1
        MyArray(i) = MyCell.Value
        Sheets("Dinâmicas").Activate
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Escritório").CurrentPage = "(All)"
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Escritório")
            If i <= 1 Then
            .PivotItems(MyArray(i)).Visible = True
            Else
            .PivotItems(MyArray(i)).Visible = True
            .PivotItems(MyArray(i - 1)).Visible = False
            End If
        End With
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica4").PivotFields("Externo").CurrentPage = "(All)"
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica4").PivotFields("Externo")
            If i <= 1 Then
            .PivotItems(MyArray(i)).Visible = True
            Else
            .PivotItems(MyArray(i)).Visible = True

            .PivotItems(MyArray(i - 1)).Visible = False
            End If
        End With
    End If


    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: O VBA acusa alguma mensagem de erro? O que acontece de errado exatamente?

Comment: por exemplo, o MyArray(i) = "Pedro" ai ele devia ir nas duas dinâmicas e selecionar apenas o pedro, e na próxima iteração, o outro funcionário que tem mais de vinte pendências, porém ele não marca apenas uma pessoa por vez, ele acaba marcando outras. Eu queria um código que desmarca tudo, e marca só o index da vez.